# Is there a better way to look through a string and find a series of letters in a set pattern than to look through it one by one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Say I have a string `a`, and inside could be `"h.e.l.l.o."`, `"h.e...l.l...o."` or even `"h.e..l..o"`. Really any series of lowercase alphabet letters can be in there. (I am using `.` as a placeholder for any random letter, just to make it look clearer)

I want to go through the string and see if the letters `h` `e` `l` `l` `o` (in that order) exists anywhere inside that string, and also return the position to me.

Here is my code:

```
import random as r
a = r.choice("hellooooo","hheelllloo","vhweclgljom","hqleeldo","hueqlbo")
"             hello       h e ll  o     h e l l o    h le l o   h e l o"
# notice the first three all have "hello" in order inside the string somewhere, and the last two don't

if "h" in a:
    i = a.index("h")
    if "e" in a[i:]:
        j = a[i:].index("e")
        if "l" in a[j:]:
            k = a[j:].index("l")
            if "l" in a[k:]:
                l = a[k:].index("l")
                if "o" in a[l:]:
                    m = a[l:].index("o")
                    print("found at",i,j,k,l,m)
```

I don't particularly want a crazy staircase like this in my code. Another way is to loop through it, but that is much slower. is there any other way to do this efficently?

Comment: Why exactly do you need the positions?

Answer (score 2):

You can go fancy and yet concise by turning the text into an iterator:

```
def find(text, pattern):
    i = iter(text)
    return all(char in i for char in pattern)
```

This uses the fact that the membership test moves the iterator only as far ahead as is needed (i.e. the index after the find).

```
>>> find("foohbarelbaloz", "hello")
True
>>> find("foohbarelbalz", "hello")
False
```

And this, in deed, does enforce the correct order:

```
>>> find("olleh", "hello")
False
```

To find the actual indeces, you can use [`str.find(sub[, start[, end]])`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

```
def find(text, pattern):
    res, i = [], -1
    for char in pattern:
        i = text.find(char, i+1) 
        if i < 0:
            raise IndexError("Not found")
        res.append(i)
    return res

>>> find("foohbarelbaloz", "hello")
[3, 7, 8, 11, 12]
```

Comment: does `char in i` consume the iterator?

Comment: It does, but only to the first hit. It has to, because that's the only way to check

Comment: could you provide an extra explanation?

Comment: I thought I did by the extra sentence =) lemme think of sth

Comment: after the comprehension will it be reduced by a size equal to `len(pattern)`?

Comment: No, if found, it will move the iterator to the letter after the last one found from pattern. Otherwise, if not found, the iterator will be exhausted. Just try it with some examples: `i = iter("abcde"); "c" in i; list(i)` will reveal a lot

Answer (score 1):

A loop is definitely the way to go -- you only need to loop through the string once.  (Note that calling `index` will loop through the string each time you call it, so you're not really avoiding a loop by calling `index` a bunch of times.)

```
def find_hidden_word(needle, haystack):
    matches = []
    for i, char in enumerate(haystack):
        if not needle:
            break
        if char == needle[0]:
            needle = needle[1:]
            matches.append(i)
    return [] if needle else matches

print(find_hidden_word("hello", "vhweclgljom"))
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```